# How can I use tailwing(tw.macro) when I'm passing a function as a prop (next.js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

**Sidebar.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Props } from './SidebarRow.i';
import tw from 'twin.macro';

function SidebarRow({ Icon, title }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Icon tw={'h-6 w-6'} />.    <------  Icon is not defined
      <p>{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarRow;
```

**SidebarRow.i.tsx**

```
import { SVGProps } from 'react';

export interface Props {
  Icon: (props: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) => JSX.Element;
  title: string;
}
```

I tried using like `const SVGIcon = styled(Icon)` but didn't work ...do I need to do something fancy on the interface ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around to make the code work but I wonder if there is a better way, this looks a bit tricky...

```
import React from 'react';
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro';

import { Props } from './SidebarRow.i';

function SidebarRow({ Icon, title }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <IconWrapper>
        <Icon />
      </IconWrapper>
      <p>{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SidebarRow;

const IconWrapper = styled.div`
  > svg {
    ${tw`h-6 w-6`}
  }
`;
```